# Is it my RAM or my Hard disk thats hanging my new Graphic card at POST or the first screen that shows up when the computer starts?

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, bios

[My Computer Specification](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c00683778&tmp_task=prodinfoCategory&lc=en&dlc=en&cc=us&site=null&key=null&product=3198158)

[My Motherboard specification](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c00714533&tmp_task=prodinfoCategory&lc=en&dlc=en&cc=us&site=null&key=null&product=3198158)

[My new Graphic Card](http://www.nvidia.com/object/geforce_8400.html)

Some days ago I bought a GeForce 8400 GS Graphic card.

My computer satisfied all the minimum system requirements it required. After installing the Card in PCI Express Slot I started the computer. But it now hangs at the POST screen i.e.(the first screen when the PC loads).

It hangs at Checking NVRAM.

I had checked the graphic card on other PC and its works perfectly. So I think there's **no problem in the Graphic card**.

If I remove my graphic card and run my PC with built in Graphic card, my PC works and doesn't hang. I upgraded my BIOS but still no fruit. My PSU is of 400W and there no problem in it.

Do I need to disable RAID or is it the problem with my RAM?